# Using Django with mostly Static pages

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am new to web development and am working on a site for my yacht club. Because we needed the ability to have accounts and login users who are members, have calendars, polls, etc. ... we decided to go with Django because it is touted to be relatively easy to use, and I am familiar with Python.

In our index.html we have written the static html to have a menu system that displays content based on whether the user has been authenticated or not in Django. The problem I am running into is that the menu works as expected unless we navigate away from it. The menu no longer shows up and it SHOULD show up in all of the pages that the user goes to.

I have placed this into one of the pages that index.html links to when I did a google search and it was suggested that this should work but it does not.

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get("/", function(data){
    $("#msa_TopNavbar").replaceWith(data);
});
</script>
```

I am at a complete loss of how to make this function. I have considered creating each page an a Django app within my project even if it is just a static page. I have also thought perhaps that index.html should just be a template and all static pages inherit from it to include the menu as well.

I recognise that this might be a huge question for a single stackoverflow question, but I don't know whether the issue is Django related or it's an HTML/javascript problem.

And yes, I have followed the tutorials of Django but they don't lend themselves to solving this kind of problem.

Comment: Please provide the code of the pages you want to debug. What do you mean that the nav bar disappears 'when you navigate away from it'? What is the purpose of the JS function you have snipped above?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing **a lot** of extra work.  Instead of fetching the html data with a jQuery call, you can just use Django's template system.

On the html page:

```
{% include 'header.html' %}

... rest of the page here

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Then on header.html you put the navbar html data.  Typically you would make a file for `header.html` and `footer.html` and on those files you put all the scripts/stylesheet links that you need for every page, then instead of typing the same html data at the top of every page, you just `{% include header.html' %}`

You may need to read up on Django's [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/).  They can be a bit difficult to work with at times.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Jane. That is definitely the way I want to go, but I was able to at least get it to work in the interim by putting the msa_TopNavbar into a top level <div> in my static page... My goal is to just "get it to work" and then go back and do it right. Unfortunately being in a time crunch leaves it vulnerable to this.